# Spring Boot Logging not working when Spring PropertySource External File with External Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have a spring boot war application which is deployed in external tomcat container.
All logs are printing properly but if application.properties file read from external path then no log is printing.
Note: iam using logback but not added logback.xml file. All log configurations were added in the application.properties .

-here is my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
   @PropertySource(value = "file:E:/Config/myApplication.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound= false)})
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyMain.class);
    }

}

application.properties .

logging.file.name=E:/FILES/LOG/myclass-logging.log
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{40}.%M - %msg%n
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=E:/FILES/LOG/myclass`enter code here`-logging-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
logging.file.max-size=5MB
logging.level.org.hibernate: OFF
```

Comment: This link may be help you. Please check it: - https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/

Comment: if the application.properties file is inside the class path then logs are printing. But when i change its path then only logs are not getting printed.

Comment: i think it is a bug.i use 2 application.properties file. one of them in resource folder contains logging properties and one of the is external contains other properties.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration

> Since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created,
> it is not possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring
> @Configuration files. The only way to change the logging system or
> disable it entirely is through System properties.